# Syntax error 3075 in calling from another procedure

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I m trying to filter records between two dates on a split form through Search button which calls the following code

```
Sub search()

Dim strCriteria ,taSk As String 

Me.Refresh
If IsNull(Me.txtDiaryDatefrom) Or IsNull(Me.txtDiaryDateTo) 
Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter Date Range", vbInformation, "Date Range Required"
    Me.txtDiaryDatefrom.SetFocus 
Else
    strCriteria = "([DiaryDate]>= # " & Me.txtDiaryDatefrom & " # And [DiaryDate] <= #" & Me.txtDiaryDateTo & " # )"
    taSk = "SELECT * from tblDiary where ( " & strCriteria & ")"
    DoCmd.ApplyFilter , taSk 
End If 

End Sub
```

Upon execution it gives the Run-time error 3075 reading

> syntax error in query expression 'Select * from tblDiary .....

Could anyone figure out what is needed to fix it ??

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the spaces between the hashes.

`"([DiaryDate]>= #" & Me.txtDiaryDatefrom & "# And [DiaryDate] <= #" & Me.txtDiaryDateTo & "# )"`

I would change the query so that the end `[DiaryDate] < Date + 1`.  This will ensure that records that have date/time values will not accidentally get filtered out.

`"([DiaryDate]>= #" & DateValue(Me.txtDiaryDatefrom) & "# And [DiaryDate] < #" & DateValue(Me.txtDiaryDateTo) + 1 & "# )"`